# Linux NASM and ID3LIB

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, nasm, id3lib

I need to call some procedures from the ID3LIB for MP3 process on Linux NASM X86 but I don't have idea how should I do this.

I already added the libid3-3.8.3-dev, libid3-3.8.3c2a and libid3-tools to my O.S (Linux Ubuntu 14.04) and the id3/ is callable from C and C++ IDEs (example id3/tag.h). I think that the EXTERN instruction maybe has something to do here but I don't know how should I call it

The main target of this code is to open a MP3 file using NASM and do modifications on his content

HINT: I can do this job with ID3LIB or FFMPEG, Which could be the easier option?

Comment: To get help easier, provide details. How do you do it from C (please give a code example in your question)? Which architecture is it (i386, amd64 etc.)? Show the assembly code you've already written, and indicate which part is missing. Exactly which functions do you need to call, and what are their declarations in the `.h` file. Why can't you do the entire file processing from C instead of assembly?

Comment: I need to do this using assembly or inline assembly using C or C++ but I have other kind of troubles on inline assembly. I've already added the headers #include <id3/tag.h> but when I do something like 

ID3_Tag mySong("mysong.mp3");

I get the following error:  `ID3_Tag::ID3_Tag(char const*)'  not defined 

About the assembly code, I just don't have nothing relative to the mp3 processing, just some console messages output and input

Comment: To get help easier, please post the entire contents of all relevant source files you already have. Please post the full error messages (including file names and line numbers). In general, you should provide as much information as you possibly can, so you are not wasting the time of people who can help you by forcing them to do several rounds of clarification questions.

Comment: I've already posted the C++ code that I've tried before. Check it please